# I've become attached to my weapons. Can I upgrade them, so I can keep them as I level up?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, equipment, character-advancement

My character started at level 1 and after many battles against goblins and such, has become slightly renowned. However, with renown comes people looking to me for help. To help I need proper equipment and my old rapier won't cut it. But my character has become quite attached to his rapier (Which he stole from a pirate.)

My question is there any way I can upgrade my old weapon, rather than sell it and buy a new one? The weapon is unmodified, no masterwork or enchantments. We are playing in the Pathfinder system however my GM is willing to allow things from D&D 3.5

Comment: Is it Masterwork?

Comment: The short answer is *Yes.* The bigger question is *How?* That is, what do you mean by upgrade (magic and special materials are most common), and how cool is the weapon you've now? And, because it's important, how new to *Pathfinder* are you and what research have you done? (This is not to mock your newness but to get an idea of the depth that an answer needs to help you. We were all new once.)

Comment: Honestly, I've been playing for many years as a DM and usually my players just ditch their weapons for the newer better things they find. So until now this hasn't been an issue.

Comment: (By the way, [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76125/how-to-calculate-the-costs-of-a-weapon-enchantment/76128#76128)'s answers provide a quick rundown of how to price a magic weapon in *Pathfinder*.)

Comment: I can hardly believe we haven’t asked and answered this question already, but I can’t find it.

Comment: One thing that will help make PCs want to hang on to things is to give those things a backstory. Name the weapon, make it fancy, maybe draw a pic of it... As long as it's just "Longsword <dmg codes>" no one will care.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The d20 SRD describes how to [create magic weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#creatingMagicWeapons) in D&D 3.5. Or there's the [Pathfinder version of the same basic rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons).

The 3.5 version starts off with:

> To create a magic weapon, a character needs a heat source and some iron, wood, or leatherworking tools. She also needs a supply of materials, the most obvious being the weapon or the pieces of the weapon to be assembled. **Only a masterwork weapon can become a magic weapon,** and the masterwork cost is added to the total cost to determine final market value.

(Emphasis added. Pathfinder has the same requirement.)

So, if the item is of masterwork quality, your character could hire a mage to enchant the weapon, making it a magic item. This is what [Erik](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/16477/erik) alluded to in his [comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94655/keeping-my-old-weapons#comment218900_94655).

This means giving up the weapon temporarily to some Mage somewhere. And paying them whatever fees they charge.

Comment: If the system is Pathfinder, the spell *masterwork transformation* will allow him to keep the same weapon.

Comment: Awesome then I'll see if there is a spell caster in town capable of doing that for me.

Comment: Related, and perhaps worth adding a paragraph written around it: [Is there any way to craft "masterwork" upgrade for weapons?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93996)

Comment: If you have a malleable GM, you could just ask to "pay the smith" the cost difference to reforge the weapon to make it masterwork, and like the answer above pay a mage to enchant it likewise.

Comment: "malleable GM." That phrase is awesome.