# Does the +1 enchant bonus for masterwork weapons apply to enchantment cost calculation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

A weapon must be masterwork to be [enchanted](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/), it also must have +1 enhancement bonus before it can be enchanted. Does the +1 enhancement bonus* from being [masterwork](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/) apply?

Example Calculation: +1 Benevolent Rapier

Rapier         20gp

Masterwork    300gp

Benevolent   2000gp

Total:       2320gp

*Note: This is a non-magical bonus to attack rolls

Comment: Hi, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [touur] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you'll be able to join us in [chat].

Comment: Does the +1 enchantment bonus apply to what, exactly? This question is a bit unclear (as shown by what appear to be two answers pointing out different things)

Comment: It seems i misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Erik, as far as I can tell, based on the price in his example, is he's wanting a MWK weapon to *COUNT* as a +1 Weapon for the purpose of enchanting.  See his calculation for a +1 Benevolent Rapier price.

Comment: [Awfully close, but I'll let the community decide if this is a duplicate.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76125/8610)

Comment: Not suggesting close/open, but *enhancement* versus *enchantment* may be part of the misunderstanding here.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I was just about to write the same. Technically, the weapon must first be *made magical* — it's unfortunate the d20 System lacks a good term for this — *then* the weapon can have added to it magic weapon special abilities. While *AD&D* and *AD&D 2e* synonymize *enchantment* with *make magical* (as do many video games), the d20 System doesn't, using *enchantment* exclusively as a term for the school of magic dealing with charming and the like.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Per my comments with KRyan, I am not sure the person asking the question is clear on the distinction.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast (I noticed your comments on that answer after I posted my comment. Maybe the asker is clear now? `:-)`)

Comment: AFAIK it's never officially referred to as enchanting because DnD & Pathfinder have the Enchantment school of spells. Because of this, weapons are universally called simply 'magic weapons' and you can make them magic giving them and enhancement bonus (not at all confusing of course). That being said, it is common for the term enchantment to be used in place of 'making a weapon magic' outside of game rules, so I don't see how that applies to this question. Unless OP doesn't know the difference.

Comment: @Ifusaso Because the term +1 *enchantment bonus* was used, and the point on terminology is as you (and KRyan) point out, the distinction may or may not be clear to the person asking. (It's obviously clear to you).  I'll point out that the *Enchantment* school of magic was introduced in AD&D 1e (Spells like Command, etc) while there was also Enchanted Weapon, Enchant an Item, and *When a magic-user attains 1 lth level (Wizard) or higher, he or she may enchant items or scribe magic scrolls. PHB page 25)*  (Looks like the Pathfinder use of Enhancement was an attempt to reduce confusion)

Comment: So... should we edit the post to use appropriate terms (for future searches) or leave it as is, since the mistaken words is part of it? Or change it to ask about the vocabulary as part of the question?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast You were correct I wasn't entirely clear on the distinction, thanks.

Comment: @Ifusaso Traditionally, the confusion of terms should be addressed by any answers. That is, the asker, it's assumed, posed the question as the asker understood it, and it's up to answers to deal with that mix-up. (I'd even go so far as to recommend the asker not edit the question to put things in "correct" terms now that answers have addressed the confusion! If the asker does anyway, answers  end up addressing a now absent issue!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It does not

This is explained on [Magic Weapons](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/):

> A magic weapon is enhanced to strike more truly and deliver more damage. Magic weapons have enhancement bonuses ranging from +1 to +5. They apply these bonuses to both attack and damage rolls when used in combat. All magic weapons are also masterwork weapons, but **their masterwork bonuses on attack rolls do not stack with their enhancement bonuses on attack rolls**.

You will notice that though both add an [enhancement bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Enhancement-Bonus), the [masterwork's enhancement bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/#masterwork-weapons) is **not** a [magic weapon's enhancement bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Magic-Weapons), which is required before you can add a [Special Ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Magic-Weapons) to weapons:

> Creating a magic weapon has a special prerequisite: The creator’s caster level must be at least three times the enhancement bonus of the weapon. If an item has both an enhancement bonus and a special ability, the higher of the two caster level requirements must be met. **A magic weapon must have at least a 1 enhancement bonus to have any melee or ranged special weapon abilities**.

Though both are enhancement bonuses, a masterwork weapon is *not* a **magic weapon** yet. It becomes a magical weapon once you bestow the first **+1** magical enhancement bonus on it, as explained on [this answer about calculating the costs of a magical weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76125/how-to-calculate-the-costs-of-a-weapon-enchantment).

The distinction here, and better explained on [Ryan's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/102428/21153), is that the *masterwork*'s enhancement bonus is applied on your *attack rolls*, while the *magic weapon*'s enhancement bonus is applied on the weapon, which increases your attack rolls aswell. Being bonuses of the same *type*, they don't stack.

Answer (score 28):

Ah, no. This is one of those “could they not afford a thesaurus?” moments, where they keep using the same word for slightly different things.

There is a difference between an enhancement bonus *to some particular roll*, and an enhancement bonus *to the weapon itself*, which is a property that items can have. They re-use the name because enhancement bonuses to items usually result in those items giving enhancement bonuses to certain things, but it’s still pretty unclear.

Being a masterwork weapon adds a +1 enhancement bonus *to attack rolls*. Having a +1 enhancement bonus *to a weapon* **also** adds a +1 enhancement bonus to attack rolls, as well as a +1 enhancement bonus to damage, but it is also more than that. For example, having a +1 enhancement bonus to the weapon also improves its hit points and hardness, allows it overcome DR /magic, and makes it eligible to receive special weapon properties. Having a weapon that offers enhancement bonuses on some or all rolls relevant to that weapon’s use *is not* the same as having an enhancement bonus to the weapon.

Since a +1 weapon is always also a masterwork weapon, it has two separate +1 enhancement bonuses to attack rolls, and these don’t stack.

And when the rules say that a magic weapon must have a +1 enhancement bonus before you can add special properties, it means that it must be a +1 weapon, not merely that it must have enhancement bonuses to the right rolls. So even if you found some other way to add a +1 enhancement bonus to the weapon’s damage, and also had a +1 enhancement bonus to attack because it’s masterwork, that still wouldn’t quite qualify.

That means your *+1 benevolent rapier* needs to be a rapier (20 gp), that is masterwork (+300 gp), that has a +1 enhancement bonus (+2,000 gp), and then has the *benevolent* property (+6,000 gp for going from +1-equivalent to +2-equivalent). Total cost is 8,320 gp. With 2,320 gp, you can only afford a *+1 rapier*.

In neat tabular form:

| Item or enhancement | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| rapier | 20 gp |
| masterwork | 300 gp |
| +1 enhancement | 2,000 gp |
| *benevolent* property | 6,000 gp |
| **Total** | **8,320 gp** |

In this case, the order they’re written is also the order in which these have to be applied: each line is a requirement for the next one.

Comment: @KRyan The OP's links uniformly use the term "enhancement bonus".  You use the term "enhancement" separately.  I don't see where the OP's links include that.  Did you invent the stand alone "enhancement" term?  If not, can you point out where in the rules it comes from?  In fact, on the magic weapons page, "enhancement" without "bonus" is used *exactly once*, and not in any way related to this problem.  Hence my request for rules quotes.

Comment: @Yakk, its colloquially used as the same term.  KRyan isn't inventing anything.

Comment: @Yakk, cherry-quoting KRyan won't prove your point, and if you want to debate his or my question further, I suggest you start a chat room for it, cause this has past comment-level conversation.

Comment: @Yakk You are correct, I misremembered how this is worded. The distinction, then, is between an enhancement bonus *to a roll*, and an enhancement bonus *to a weapon*. A masterwork weapon offers an enhancement bonus to attack rolls made with it, but it does not, itself, *have* an enhancement bonus. A +1 weapon, on the other hand, does *have* an enhancement bonus, that is, there is a +1 enhancement bonus to the weapon.

Comment: @KRyan Ah, that might be it.  So the masterwork weapon *grants* an enhancement bonus to attack rolls.  The magic weapon *has* an enhancement bonus, which it also *grants* to attack rolls (and damage rolls).  The enhancement bonus an item *has* is probably referred to elsewhere, like in item saving throws.  (grants might be the wrong term)

Comment: @Yakk Item hit points and hardness is what I thought of, but yeah, saving throws quite likely as well.

Comment: @KRyan to be honest, that was the point of my answer, but i guess i couldn't explain it properly.

Comment: Comments removed, and answer is even better now.

Answer (score 10):

**No**

A MWK weapon does not count as a +1 weapon for crafting purposes, and doesn't even give the benefits of a +1 weapon.  Let's compare real quick:

MWK:

- +1 enhancement bonus on attack rolls

+1:

- +1 enhancement bonus on attack rolls
- +1 enhancement bonus on damage rolls
- Overcome DR as a +1 magic weapon
- Treated as a magic item instead of a mundane item for various ancillary purposes.

As you can see, the value of these two attributes is *different*.

If you wanted a +1 Benevolent weapon, you'd pay:

```
Rapier        20gp
Masterwork  +300gp
+1 Weapon  +2000gp
Benevolent +6000gp(8000gp total enchantment costs)
Total       8320gp
```

Comment: Can you quote the that requires you have a "+1 weapon"?  I can find many rules that states you must have a weapon with at least a +1 enhancement bonus, but I can find no rules in the pathfinder srd that requires a "+1 weapon".

Comment: "A weapon with a special ability must also have at least a +1 enhancement bonus."  MWK does not give the *weapon* a +1 enhancement bonus.

Comment: State that in your answer.  You claim that they are different, and that one doesn't qualify, but you don't state why or where the rules state that this difference is important.